# Recreate Modal look

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that needs to look like the image attached but after trying several CSS styles I cannot make it look like the image attached. Tried various libraries like Materialize but problems in the project. Therefore please make your answers in **Bootstrap modals**. The modal/popup should be transparent and look the same. Hoping to get some help from someone that is good in bootstrap or CSS.

[image]

`

### Modal Example

```
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Headers</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the test</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and use the following JS

`$("#errorMessageModal").modal({backdrop: false});
 $("#errorMessageModal").modal("show");`

Comment: can you please create jsfiddle or something like that?

Comment: Also, did you try using chrome to inspect the modal you wanted to replicate? There is a chance that they are also using bootstrap and you'll be able to see what they changed to get it to work.

Comment: This is a mockup I could not inspect. Obviously I would have thought of that first. Creating a fiddle would be difficult because I am new to angular and the project is run in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are *required by your client/boss* to use Bootstrap modal for this, forget Bootstrap modal, and go along with a mostly CSS based solution:

This code does not require any additional libraries, other than you already have (jQuery). The animation is done in CSS.

The `.content-mock` div is just there to show how content would be overlapped by this message window.

```js
$("#showbottom").click(function(){
  $("#bottom-message").toggleClass('bottom-message-open');
});
```

```css
.bottom-message {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
}

.bottom-message-open {
    max-height: 100px;
    -moz-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
}

.bottom-message-content {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="showbottom" value="toggle bottom message"/>

<div class="content-mock" style="height: 300px; background-color: #c10; margin-top: 30px;">
    This div is here to show some dummy content
</div>

<div class="bottom-message" id="bottom-message">
    <div class="bottom-message-content">
      The content of message go here
    </div>
</div>
```